# Merging code from local branch to master branch, but as a single commit

Tags: git

I worked on a local branch, and I pushed 10 commits.
Now I want to merge those commits to master branch, but it has to be just one commit containing all the 10 commits.

I've read about rebasing but as far as I can tell it's rewriting history in the local branch.

Comment: You're looking for a rebase + squash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a *squash merge*.  It's not really a merge at all, though: a merge—more precisely, a *merge commit*, with "merge" used as an adjective, or as a noun when we abbreviate it to "a merge"—is a commit with two (or even more, but two is all it takes) *parent* commits, that therefore joins two earlier divergent histories.  A "squash merge", in Git, makes an ordinary single-parent commit, using all of the merging *action*—"merge as a verb"—that a regular merge would do, but deliberately failing to record the result as a merge.

In other words, to merge-as-a-verb, but get a not-merge-as-a-noun ordinary commit as a result, you use Git's "squash merge":

```
git merge --squash <otherbranch>
```

This does all the work of a merge, but then makes an ordinary commit.

Except, for some reason, `--squash` *also* turns on `--no-commit` automatically, so that after the squash action finishes, you must run `git commit` yourself.

(You can use `--no-commit` without `--squash`, to get the same "pause after merging-as-a-verb" effect.  The commit you make in this case is a real merge commit.)

Note that once you make a squash-y ordinary commit, it's rarely any good to do any more work on the branch you have squashed.  It's usually wisest to abandon (and eventually delete) that branch.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the delay!